# What is the point of subtracting 1/Fs from the time variable

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, sampling

I have a rather simple question, sorry in advance if it's too easy. I'm working on a waveform generation project on MATLAB. When I look at the examples, I see that the time variables are defined like this;

```
t = 0:1/fs:T-1/fs;
```

What is the point of `-1/fs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a matter of personal preference.

- Some prefer that the length $N$ of the vector $t$ matches $$N =
     \lfloor f_sT\rfloor$$ where $\lfloor\rfloor$denotes the $\mathrm{floor}()$ function. This is done so that $$\frac{N}{f_s}
     \leq T$$

  **Example 1**: $f_sT$ is an integer: $f_s = 200\,\texttt{Hz}$, $T = 3\texttt{s}$ so $N = 600$:

  ```
  t = 0:1/fs:T % length(t) = 601, which would give 601/200 = 3.005s
  t = 0:1/fs:T-1/fs % length(t) = 600, which gives 3s
  ```

  **Example 2**: $f_sT$ is not an integer: $f_s = 200\,\texttt{Hz}$, $T = 3.142\texttt{s}$ so $N = \lfloor628.4\rfloor = 628$:

  ```
  t = 0:1/fs:T % length(t) = 629, which would give 629/200 = 3.145s
  t = 0:1/fs:T-1/fs % length(t) = 628, which gives 628/200 = 3.14s
  ```

---

- However, others prefer that the last sample of $t$ be as close to $T$
  as possible:
  With `t = (0:1/fs:T)`, the very last sample of `t` will
  be closer to `T`:

  **Example 1**:

  ```
     t = 0:1/fs:T % t(end) = 3s
     t = 0:1/fs:T-1/fs % t(end) = 2.995s
  ```

  **Example 2**:

  ```
     t = 0:1/fs:T % t(end) = 3.14s
     t = 0:1/fs:T-1/fs % t(end) = 3.135s
  ```

---

- Finally, see @Vito's [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/85600/63763)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends what they are trying to do, but I assume they simulate several chunks of duration `T` with sampling interval `1/fs`.

So they need to make sure that the last sample of each chunk is not computed again as the first sample of the next chunk.